# Wrap to next coloumn if overflowed container

Tags: html, css

I would like to achieve the following layout if the content overflows the container:

[image]

So say if the container is 400px in height, if the content flows over that it creates a new column.

I have created a starter fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Gkzc8. The red box represents the container and its height.

Comment: jsFiddle isn't loading for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gkzc8/4/)

Use CSS3 `multi-column`

```
#miked {height:400px; background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.3); -moz-column-count: 3; column-count: 3; /*overflow: hidden*/}
```

Read on [**Multi-column**](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html)